# Semantic similarity (text comparison) in NLP - best package or cloud service?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to find readymade service for text comparison (the meaning of sentences including consideration of synonyms)

I found out that AWS Comprehend does not support text comparison. I am looking for a trusted way to quickly implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information "text comparison" is very broad. If there is an example of the expected functionality, we can help better. Following are some points regarding semantics with Python's library for WORDNET.

1. This offers a way to identify synonyms, hypernymy, and hyponymy.
2. This also offers a way to measure the distance between two words and thereby helps in comparing the "proximity" of those words.
3. Please note that WORDNET is a collection of NOUNS and does not have all the words in English.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SprinkeML](https://sprinkleml.com) to do word comparisons and it's worked well.